# Prestashop: "An error occurred while sending the message."

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I am using PrestaShop 1.7 with its default theme.
I also have contact form module installed.

But when I try to send a message from the "contact us page" using the contact form created by the contact form module.

It throws the error below :

> An error occurred while sending the message, please try again.

[image: An error occurred while sending the message, please try again.]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured out the problem.

Actually, I'd tried to upgrade my shop to 1.7.3.1 when the notification first popped up. Then somehow the installation went wrong but the module I was using, which was 1-Click Upgrade, was saying something like "*don't worry we will recover to the version that you were using before.*".

Well, they didn't! And I hadn't thought this could be the problem at first.

Then I started thinking about which file or files could have possibly been changed. Using an online file compare tool I saw that **contactform.php** in **/modules/contactform** was different than the one I was using before.

After changing that file to the older one the problem was solved!

If that file was not the case for you I recommend you to try other files if you'd tried to upgrade the version to the newer one and failed during the process just like me.

Hope this helps people having the same issue without having to think about for days like me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you haven't properly working email server but after each contact form's submission, an e-mail message sends to admin e-mail address(by default). To avoid the problem you can set up your email server correctly(on your server then in your prestashop admin panel) or just turn off the option in **Advanced Parameters -> E-mail -> Never send emails**(in this case an admin won't receive a message to his e-mail only to admin panel). Also here you can test whether your email server works properly or not by sending of test e-mail to your own address via the last form **Test your email configuration**.
Hope my suggestions will help you.

Comment: I already have my own e-mail server installed and working properly. But the thing is that, **even when I change** the SMTP user to some other user account that I have on my server. The sender is not changing. It is still the same one as before. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Did you try to send a test mail from your admin panel? Did you receive a test message to your e-mail if you had tried to send it?

Comment: Yes I've tried to send test mails using php mail() function and also using my own SMTP configuration. I've receive both of the messages. **But** as I mentioned on my other comment below. Even when I change the SMTP user, the mails are still coming from the same account as before. That's interesting.

Comment: When you turn off mail sending(Never send emails (may be useful for testing purposes)) does a problem stay?

Comment: When I turn off the mail sending option as you said, it is still giving the same error.

Comment: If so, I don't even know what to suggest you. Try to debug modules/contactform/contactform.php sendMessage method to get a notion where from a problem come and in which step it occurs. Maybe the problem not with mail sending at all.

Comment: Well thank you I've just fixed the problem. See my answer above. Thank you for your time anyway, I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, to make sure setup email function correctly. Usually, people use PHP mail function to send the email, but it's a not good idea - sometime, this function has been disabled by hosting provider, and your emails delivered to Junk instead of Inbox.

Login to admin panel -> Click on ADVANCED PARAMETERS and then on “Email” tab.

Then you can choose PHP Mail function or SMTP server to send the email.

I wrote an article about **[Prestashop SMTP Setting](https://www.prestasoo.com/Blog/prestashop-smtp-settings-so-easy.html)**. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've noticed that all three of your answers on this site contain links to your own blog. While StackOverflow's [promotion guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) say that it's OK to promote your own site as long as you provide disclosure (which you've done - good job!), it also advises that your answers should be useful even without the link, and that you shouldn't include a link to your blog in *every* one of your answers. Doing small things like this will increase the quality of your answers and hopefully lead to more upvotes :)

Comment: Well, I've tried all these things many times but nothing happens. Even when I choose "never send e-mails" option, nothing appears in the customer service tab and it is still throwing the same error on contact form page after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

problem is i think in lang folder not exits

you can change line 418
          $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->trans('An error occurred while sending the message, please try again.', array(), 'Modules.Contactform.Shop');

to
$this->context->controller->errors[] = $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];

this way easy for you to see the full error report

for me error is .lang/ folder not exits

wish up solution help you little.

Comment: Not sure why this has initially been down voted as it is a good way to debug where the problem comes from.